# jquery validation of email field with php, mysql and validate plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, jquery-validate

I'm having some strange problems using the validation plugin with jquery. This seems to have been asked a few times, but i cannot find the answer to my problem.  I've got a form, and I am trying to see if the email has already been entered - if it has, the user should not be able to submit the form.  I'm using FirePHP to output various variables.  This is where I notice that the return value of my query is always "1" (which is wrong).  However, when I manually query my db (using PhpMyAdmin), the correct answer ("0") comes up.

Here is my js:

```
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        ......
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "check_email.php" , async:false 
        }, 
    },
    messages: {
                     ......
        email: {required: "Please enter an email address", email: "Please enter a valid email address", remote: "This email is already registered" },
        }
    }
});
```

});

And here is my php after the db connection stuff...

```
$form_email = $_GET['email'];
fb($form_email);


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM users WHERE email = " . "'" . $form_email . "'"; 
fb($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
fb($result->num_rows);

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'true';
    fb("true");
} else {
       echo 'false';
    fb("false");
 }
```

The count is always returned as "1", even when I input an email that does not exist.

I've also tried returning

```
echo json_encode('true');
```

as I read somewhere that might work, but it did not help.  Why is my response always wrong in my php?

Comment: `async` is not a rule.  Check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `remote` rule is not correct:

```
rules: {
    ......
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: "check_email.php" , async:false 
    }, 
}
```

The way you've written it, the plugin is seeing `async` as just another rule.  Since there is no such "rule" as `async`, the plugin will choke.

[Following the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options), try this:

```
rules: {
    ......
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: "check_email.php"
    }
}
```

or this...

```
rules: {
    ......
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: "check_email.php", 
            async: false 
        }
    } 
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/KkBSY/**

Comment: Changed my js to "remote: "check_email.php" but still no luck.

Comment: @KathyLyons, as you can see, the plugin is working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/KkBSY/  But there's too much missing from your OP for me to help you much further.  Where's the rendered HTML of your form?